# How do I test for two conditions at the same time in Foundry while running a fuzz test?

Tags: solidity, foundry, fuzz-test

Let us say I am trying to fuzz simple addition b/w two 'uint' variables in Solidity using foundry, I expect one of two conditions to happen:

1. The test passes without overflow error.
2. The test fails with the compiler reverting because of overflow.

How do I configure my fuzz test function to expect both of those conditions at the same time?
As in I want the test to pass if either of the conditions are true, but fail for anything else.
[image]
Basically, I want my test function to check for two conditions at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

How about codes below?

```
function testAddition(uint256 a, uint256 b) public {
    assert(a <= (type(uint256).max - b));
}
```